# AWS dynamoDB query execution time

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

`Table Name: registration 
NO.of items:15 Million 
registration_number is primary hash key. 
name,age,mobile, address are other attributes.`

read/write capacity: 5

my Query fetch data from the registration table where the registration_number is "reg01500" .

what is the query execution time?

Comment: How mant queries happens per second?

Comment: per second 100 queries

Comment: Seems like the provisioned read capacity is not enough. Did you check on the error responses and Cloud Watch alarms?

Comment: what is minimum sufficient read capacity

Comment: Assuming that your your item size is < 4kb, it will require 100 read capacity units, since its 100 queries per second to give optimum query performance.

Comment: ok. read capacity: 1. query per second 1. item size: lessthan 4kb ,NO.of items:15 Million 
registration_number is primary hash key. 
name,age,mobile, address are other attributes. my Query fetch data from the registration table where the registration_number is "reg01500" .
now,
what is the query execution time?